# java multi-threading: using notify() and wait()

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to mimic how cpu works.

I have three classes: cpu, readyQueue, and process.

It works like this: a readyQueue contains a bunch of process, every time the cpu is available, readyQueue will load a process into cpu and run the process for only 3 SECONDS, if the process is done then kill the process, or load it back into the queue.

I make Process class implements Runnable, and treat CPU and readyQueue as shared resources.

The place where i'm stuck at is: how can i use notify() and wait() to properly let the first element in queue to acquire CPU's lock, and using wait() to release the LOCK from the process.

I've been searching online trying to find an example but couldn't find any.

Am i on the right track?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use wait-notify, rather than one of the java.util.concurrent classes?

Comment: That would be much cleaner and less error prone, but creators of homework assignments don't worry about such silly little stuff.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan hi, are you talking about blockingQueue?

Comment: I don't know enough about your situation to recommend a specific data structure.